# PHP ftp_delete can't find file

Tags: php, ftp

When I try to use ftp_delete() I get the error: Warning: ftp_delete(): File not found. My ftp server should be working fine, I can upload files fine to the same directory without a problem. Here is the PHP:

```
$fileSource = 'http://localhost/user/images/dfdf.png';
$ftpCon = ftp_connect('localhost');
ftp_login($ftpCon,'---','---');
ftp_delete($ftpCon,$fileSource);
```

Also when I look at the server logs I can see I get the message:  550 File not found

The url for $fileSource is the file's exact path, I went into localhost and copy/pasted it into the code, still for some reason it can't be found.

Comment: It's long since I last used php and I can't even remember for how long I haven't used php with ftp. But I think that the correct usage is `ftp_delete(connection, path)`, where path is relative to ftp root, not as your `$fileSource`, which is URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ftp_delete` function acccepts a path to the file. You are providing `http://localhost/user/images/dfdf.png` which contains the host (`http://localhost/`). I think you mean to provide `/user/images/dfdf.png`, which is just the path.

Example:

```
 ftp_delete($ftpCon, '/user/images/dfdf.png');
```

When, for example, your FTP root is `/user/`, it will mean you need to provide `ftp_delete` with `/images/dfdf.png`. Thanks to @maremp.

Comment: That is correct, if the ftp has same root directory as php server.